# how to inject php GraphQL query results , with queries defined in Twig(Bridge) templates, using Twig Extension in Laravel8?

Tags: php, laravel, graphql, twig, twig-extension

I've setup a laravel 8 site, with php 7.4.

I prefer Twig frontend templating to Blade.  I've installed twigbridge to enable Twig usage.
Templating works great.

I've a backend app that serves up content via GraphQL.

I want to access/reference the backend content, via GraphQL query, in my Twig templates.

I've composer-installed 'PHP GraphQL Client' (https://github.com/mghoneimy/php-graphql-client) into the Laravel app.

It provides php GraphQL query access of the form:

```
$gql = (new Query('companies'))
    ->setSelectionSet(
        [
            'name',
            'serialNumber'
        ]
    );
```

To inject query results into my Laravel/Twig templates, I'm creating a TwigExtension

I'm piecing together the Extension from scattered online posts and not much documentation.
So far I've got (not yet functional / WIP)

```
edit app/Twig/GraphqlQuery.php

    <?php

    namespace App\Twig;

    use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
    use Twig\TwigFilter;

    use GraphQL\Client;
    use GraphQL\Exception\QueryError;
    use GraphQL\Query;

    class GraphqlQuery extends AbstractExtension {

        protected $client;
        protected $query;

        public function __construct(
            Client $client,
            Query  $query
        ) {
            $this->client = $client;
            $this->query  = $query;
        }

        public function getFunctions(): array {
            return [
                new TwigFunction(
                    'gql_query',
                    [$this, 'gqlQuery']
                ),
            ];
        }

        public function gqlQuery($gql_data) {

            $gql = (new Query('twig'))
                ->setVariables(
                    [
                        new Variable('name', 'String', true),
                        new Variable('limit', 'Int', false, 5)
                    ]
                )
                ->setArguments(
                    [
                        'name' => '$name',
                        'first' => '$limit'
                    ]
                )
                ->setSelectionSet(
                    [
                        'name',
                        'serialNumber'
                    ]
                );


            try {
                $results = $this->gqlClient->runQuery($gql);
            }

            catch (QueryError $exception) {
                print_r($exception->getErrorDetails());
                exit;
            }

            $results = $this->gqlClient->runQuery($gql, true); // array structure
            return $results;
        }

    }
```

I want to get the array data for

```
->setVariables(
    [
        new Variable('name', 'String', true),
        new Variable('limit', 'Int', false, 5)
    ]
)
->setArguments(
    [
        'name' => '$name',
        'first' => '$limit'
    ]
)
->setSelectionSet(
    [
        'name',
        'serialNumber'
    ]
);
```

passed in from my Twig Templates, ideally wrapped in

```
{#graphql
```

twig tags.

1st step -- What's the right way to refactor `function gqlQuery()` to accept the array contents, properly encoded etc, from Twig Templates?

Comment: Template editors need to add content to the templates.  Content is available via GraphQL.  Twig is the template env.  I need GraphQL in Twig.
As in Drupal, https://git.drupalcode.org/project/graphql_twig
but for Laravel.

Comment: The Drupal solution is a drpal-specific solution; it's written as a Drupal module.
Which works of course for Drupal.
The TwigExtension approach is my attempt for something more generic/portable, and ideally simple, for the Laravel env I'm in.

Answer (score 0):

There won't be a simple solution for this use-case if you want to handle this inside twig. You could in fact send an array to the `TwigFunction`, e.g.

```html
{% set graph = glq_query({
    'variables': [
         [ 'name', 'String', true, ],
         [ 'limit', 'Int', false, 5 ],
    ],
    'arugments': {
        'name': '$name',
        'first': '$limit',
    },
    'selectionSet': [
        'name',
        'serialNumber',
    ],
}) %}
```

But then you would need to write validation/checks for every possible combination that could be created to control the Graph QL client

Comment: Yeah, the generic use-case solution gets fatter quickly.  For all the yapping about GraphQL, you'd hope that frameworks -- at least the big ones -- would address this.  But oh well, for now it's DIY.

Re: your snippet above, yep -- that'd work.  Tho, that's really not _much_ different than simply calling the original php. At least in terms of syntax an 'editor' will see/use.

Comment: Yes, if the people writing/editing know about the `PHP` syntax behind the framework setting up a system with arrays like this wouldn't be that inconvenient for them. Well you could start with writing the "basics" and extends from there when the need of extra's occurs

Comment: As I dig around, I'm inclined to remove abstraction -- and get rid of the https://github.com/mghoneimy/php-graphql-client altogether.

I've got php, obviously, and php-curl extension.  A TwigExtension that receives a JSON object, properly decodes, and passes to the back end directly via a `curl_exec` should do the trick.

And, the Editors would be able to structure the query as 'pure' JSON -- exactly/unaltered from a GraphiQL UI query.  So 'test it' then 'use it' ...